# How to compare two cell in each pandas DataFrame row and set result in new cell in same row

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas DataFrame, i need to create result column, that is result of comparison of two columns.

If in column SECOND - NaN, then in result column - FIRST.

If in column SECOND - not NaN, then in result column - SECOND.

|  | first | second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | test | Nan |
| 1 | test2 | test3 |

->

|  | result | first | second |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | test | test | Nan |
| 1 | test3 | test2 | test3 |

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file)
df["result"] = df["second"] if df["second"] else df["first"]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'first': ['A', 'C'],
    'second': ['B', None]
})
df['result'] = np.where(
    df['second'].isna(),
    df['first'],
    df['second']
)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function.

If your dataframe is,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first' : ['test', 'test2'], 'second' : [np.nan, 'test3']})
print(df)
```

```
    first   second
0   test    NaN
1   test2   test3
```

You can then use the apply function to create the 'result' column based on the other two columns:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['first'] if pd.isna(row['second']) 
                                    else row['second'],
               axis=1)
```

The **important** part is `axis=1` as that tells apply to use rows rather than columns.

If you'd prefer to not use a messy looking lambda function, the following code does the same thing:

```
def func(row):
    if pd.isna(row['second']):
        return row['first']
    else:
        return row['second']
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
```

Both of these produce the following dataframe:

```
    first   second  result
0   test    NaN     test
1   test2   test3   test3
```